# How can I ignore drag with IgnorePointer?

Tags: flutter, flutter-ignore-pointer

I know we can ignore pointer with the `IgnorePointer` widget, but how can I ignore just a specific event. for example, `VerticalDrag` or `tap`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to ignore a specific event, in your case `VerticalDrag` on a widget `Container`, you would have to wrap the widget in question in a `GestureDetector`

`GestureDetectors` would always try and respond to events with non-null callbacks.

So putting that all together, a simple code snippet to achieve what you wanted would probably look like this

```
GestureDetector(
        // Ignores all this events

        onVerticalDragUpdate: (_) {},

        onVerticalDragDown: (_) {},

        onVerticalDragEnd: (_) {},

        onVerticalDragStart: (_) {},

        onVerticalDragCancel: () {},

        onTap: () {},

        // Does not ignore these events below

        onDoubleTap: () {
          print('Container was double tapped');
        },
        onLongPress: () {
          print('Container was long pressed');
        },

        child: Container(),
      )
```

Comment: worth adding that events not specifically handled by the GestureDetector will also not be ignored